# time dependent ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having a trouble to understand this:

$\frac{dx}{dt}=v(x)$   $ x \in \mathbb{R}$

This is autonomous because v is independent of time.

Thats ok. My problem is when

$\frac{dx}{dt}=v(x)$   $ x \in \mathbb{R}^n$

[image: Vector differential equation]

I dont understand that argument. If $x$ is n dimensional vector the differential equation is never time independent?

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely, the text is not actually describing a time-independent system. It specifically names $V$ as a region in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n$, so there's one extra copy of $\mathbb{R}$ being included, and that's there to add $t$ as a component alongside $x$. This is what they mean by the "extended phase space".

The condition of being "nowhere parallel to $\mathbb{R}^n$" is ensuring that the system is never standing still in time but moving in space.